# On which site should I ask a question about data exporting?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On which site should I ask a question about data exporting, specifically, about getting data back from a former vendor (transportation fulfilment company)? I believe their rates are exorbitant.

The question is:

> How much should it cost to get a data dump from them.  They quoted something like $.0025 per record, which for me seems pretty high.  I'm looking for some guidelines, or a place to get ballpark estimates.

Comment: Um. What kind of question?

Comment: If you could include an example question you want to ask, that would be very helpful.

Comment: That example question does not sound like anything for the network. I would assume you'd simply have to contact them yourself.

Comment: Well I'm looking for industry standards or people with opinions to state that the price is fair, cheap, or expensive.

Comment: @flex.net And that's not an appropriate question on this network.

Comment: We don't deal in opinions though. Nowhere in the network.

Comment: Seriously? I'm not "naming" names...

Comment: Yep, seriously.

Answer (score 6):

> The question is how much should it cost to get a data dump from them

They gave you a quote. Done.

This is not a suitable question for anyone other then them to answer - it is theirs to answer.

Anything anyone would give as an answer would be speculative and be not be based on information not available outside this company.

As such - it is not something that fits the Stack Exchange model at all. We expect fact based questions and answers (for the most).

What you seem to be looking is for some sort of baseline information about data export prices that will let you haggle with them - that would be a request for off-site resources, which is also off-topic for pretty much all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Well fact based answers is only part of it.  According to the Shark vs Gorilla [http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/] post, questions that elicit references or specific expertise are game.  I've never heard of a pricing reference to be speculative.

Comment: @flex.net The conclusions of the "Gorilla vs. Shark" post don't really apply here - it is about questions that ask for a comparison and judgement between two things. The example you give is arguably more of a [shopping question.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) Asking for opinions on a price might be perfectly okay in a Stack Exchange site's chat room, though (if a Stack Exchange site for this field of expertise existed, which I don't think is the case at the moment)

Answer (score 4):

Such a question wouldn't belong anywhere on the SE network.  It's a question that you'll need to ask of that company.  It would be primarily opinion based on this network, in addition to being way too localized such that it's unlikely to be helpful to other users.

Comment: What question should I ask them? I was given a quote, and I think it's high. Am I correct in thinking so?

Comment: I'm still waiting for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: @flex.net You can ask them what the standard rates are, what other customers are paying, whether their rates are negotiable, etc.  Regardless, the point of the answer is that it's not an appropriate question on this site, as to where else you should go to get an answer, at the end of the day that's something you'll need to figure out on your own.